# mysqlfailover not switch slave to master,Missing gtid_executed system variable

Tags: mysql

i use mysqlfailover but when master down,the slave not change to master,mysqlfailover report

> ERROR: The server slave xxx.xxx.xxx.x:3306 does not comply to the
>   latest GTID feature support. Errors:
>       Missing gtid_executed system variable.

Comment: Can you specify which MySQL server version were you using with mysqlfailover?

Comment: Is there any solution you got for this problem ? Even I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with MySQL utilites version 1.5 according to the mySQL bug #80189.

MySQL Utilites version 1.6 appears to have fixed the issue.

Try downloading the beta version of the MySQL Utilites version 1.6 and try the failover again.

I was having the same issue with my failover setup but I do not have the issue since downloading and installing the newer version of MySQL Utilites.

Answer (score 0):

2015-12-01 16:21:41 PM INFO Master may be down. Waiting for 3 seconds.
2015-12-01 16:21:56 PM INFO Failed to reconnect to the master after 3 attemps.
2015-12-01 16:21:56 PM CRITICAL Master is confirmed to be down or unreachable.
2015-12-01 16:21:56 PM INFO Failover starting in 'auto' mode...
2015-12-01 16:21:56 PM INFO Unregistering instance on master.
2015-12-01 16:21:56 PM CRITICAL The server 192.168.3.111:3306 does not comply to the latest GTID feature support. Errors:
    Missing gtid_executed system variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comm